# repeated doGet call

Tags: java, servlets

My snippet of HttpServlet:

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException,
                                                                         IOException {
        final String[] values = httpServletRequest.getParameterValues("p");
        final int p;
        if (values != null && values.length > 0) {
            p = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
        } else {
            p = 0;
        }
        final ServletContext context = super.getServletContext();
        switch (p) {
        case 0:
            {

                final CityRepresentationBean bean =
                    new CityRepresentationBean(ds);
                final RequestDispatcher rqDsp;
                try {
                    rqDsp =
                            context.getRequestDispatcher(bean.act(httpServletRequest));
                    rqDsp.forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
                } catch (ConnectionException e) {
                    throw new ServletException(e);
                }
 ......
}
```

The main problem is that I get StackOverFlow Exception. From Debug I have found that I get ConnectionException then method doGet is called again (I even don't have a clue who can call it) after `throw new ServletException(e)`.

The question is How the servlet can be called several time if browser invokes URL only once?

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:303)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:523)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at project2.FrontController.doGet(FrontController.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:523)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at project2.FrontController.doGet(FrontController.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:523)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at project2.FrontController.doGet(FrontController.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:523)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at project2.FrontController.doGet(FrontController.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:523)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at project2.FrontController.doGet(FrontController.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
```

Comment: Most likely one of the conditions maps back to the same servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL pattern of that servlet is also been matched on the URL which is returned by `bean.act(httpServletRequest)` in your `RequestDispatcher#forward()`.

So, you have 2 options:

1. Map the servlet on a more specific URL pattern. At least *not* on `/*` or something. For example, `/pages/*` or `*.do`.
2. Make sure that the URL returned by `act()` doesn't match the servlet's URL pattern.

#### Related:

- [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/)